# Record h.264 from webcam as f4v from flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, h.264, flash-media-server

Using Flash Media Server, I have an pre-made application that records from webcam and microphone and publishes it to the FMS server as an FLV file.

This works fine, but I now have a need to stream this video that's been recorded to an iOS device. I've got FMS working and it can stream the hls-record/sample.f4v.m3u8 file to an iOS / quicktime device.

I've read some tutorials online and I've changed the publish(filename, "record") to publish("mp4:" + filename + ".f4v", record)

It records stores the file on the FMS server (i see it there, with the filename i gave it and as a .f4v file), it has content. When i goto play it though (via quicktime or safari) i see the length of the video (4 seconds as a test) but no video. The tracking bar doesn't move and the wait icon, waits.

FMS version 4.5 and Flash 11.3 is installed on my Mac. (CentOS 5.8 server)

I must be missing something.

```
package com
{
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.controls.ProgressBarMode;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.NetConnector
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.media.H264Level;
import flash.media.H264Profile;
import flash.media.H264VideoStreamSettings;
/**
 * ...
 * @author Alexander (flash2you) < >
 */
public class Recorder extends MovieClip
{
    private var dataHolder:DataHolder = DataHolder.getInstance()

    public var layer:MovieClip
    public var activityLevel_pb:ProgressBar
    public var aguja:MovieClip
    public var aguja2:MovieClip
    public var publishButton:MovieClip
    public var timer_txt:TextField
    public var recordStatus:MovieClip
    public var recordBtn:MovieClip

    private var netStream:NetStream
    private var microphone:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone()
    private var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera()
    public var  video:Video

    private var timer:Timer = new Timer(100)
    private var clockTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000)

    public var published:Boolean = false

    private var isRecording:Boolean = false

    private var minutero = 0;
    private var crono = 0;
    private var records = 0;


    public var settings_mc:MovieClip
    public static var recorder:Recorder
    public var settings_icon:MovieClip

    private var limitTimer:Timer
    public function Recorder()
    {
        Recorder.recorder = this;

        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, on$timer)
        clockTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, on$clockTimer)
        //visible = false


        recordBtn.buttonMode = true
        recordBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , recordBtn$click)
        recordBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, recordBtn$over)
        recordBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, recordBtn$out)

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage)


        limitTimer = new Timer(dataHolder.timelimit * 1000);
        limitTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onLimitTimerHandler)
    }

    private function onLimitTimerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
         stopPublish()
    }
    /*
     *  when we comes to second frame
     * */
    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        init()
    }
    /*
     *   function for set up camera from settings module
     * */
    public function setCamera(_camera:Camera) {
        camera = _camera
        addCameraSettings()

        video.attachCamera(camera)

        if (netStream){
            netStream.attachCamera(camera)
        }
    }

    public function setMicrophone(mic:Microphone) {
        microphone = mic;

        if (netStream){
            netStream.attachAudio(microphone)
        }

        addMicSettings()
    }

    private function addMicSettings() {
        microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
        microphone.setSilenceLevel(1)
    }

    private function addCameraSettings():void
    {
        camera.setQuality(90000, 90);
        camera.setMode(320, 240, 30, true);
        camera.setKeyFrameInterval(15);
        //camera.setMode(dataHolder.cameraWidth, dataHolder.cameraHeight, dataHolder.cameraFPS)
        //camera.setQuality(0, dataHolder.cameraQuality)
    }

    public function init() {
        startConnect()
    }
    /*
     *  main function for connection
     * */
    private function startConnect() {
        visible = true

        timer_txt.htmlText = "<b>00:00</b>";

        initCamera()
        initMicropone()
        var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection()
        nc.connect(null)
        netStream = new NetStream(nc)
        netStream.attachAudio(microphone)

        video.attachCamera(camera)
        layer.visible = false


        publishButton.gotoAndStop(1);


        activityLevel_pb.mode = ProgressBarMode.MANUAL;

        recordStatus.gotoAndStop("noRecord")

        timer.start()


        connection.addEventListener(NetConnector.CONNECTED, connectionComplete)
        connection.startConnection()
    }

    public function get connection():NetConnector {
        return dataHolder.connection
    }

    private function on$timer(e:TimerEvent) {
        activityLevel_pb.setProgress(microphone.activityLevel, 100)
    }
    /*
     *  when connection to your stream server done
     * */
    private function connectionComplete(e:Event = null) {
        netStream = new NetStream(connection)
        netStream.attachAudio(microphone)
        netStream.attachCamera(camera)
    }

    /*
     *   add 0 if less then 10secs
     * */
    private function addLeading(nbr) {
        if (nbr<10) {
            return ("0"+Math.floor(nbr));
        } else {
            return (Math.floor(nbr).toString());
        }
    }

    /*
     *   update visible clock, rotate arrows
     * */
    private function updateTimer() {
        timer_txt.htmlText = "<b>"+addLeading(crono/60)+":"+addLeading(crono%60)+"</b>";
        aguja.rotation = aguja.rotation+6;
        if (addLeading(crono/60)>minutero) {
            aguja2.rotation = aguja2.rotation+6;
            ++minutero;
        }
        // end if
        ++crono;
    }

    private function on$clockTimer(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        updateTimer()
    }
    private function startClockTimer() {
        clockTimer.start()
    }

    /*
     *  update graphics and start recording
     * */
    private function recordBtn$click(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!isRecording) {
            startRecording()
            recordStatus.gotoAndStop("record")
            recordBtn.visible = false
        }
    }

    private function recordBtn$over(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!isRecording) {
            this.gotoAndPlay(65);
        }
    }
    private function recordBtn$out(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!isRecording) {
            this.gotoAndPlay(61);
        }
    }

    private function startRecording() {
        if (connection.connected){

            var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
            h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3_1);


            netStream.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;

            netStream.publish("mp4:" + dataHolder.filename + ".f4v", "record");

            var metaData:Object = new Object();
            metaData.codec = netStream.videoStreamSettings.codec;
            metaData.profile =  h264Settings.profile;
            metaData.level = h264Settings.level;
            metaData.fps = camera.fps;
            metaData.bandwith = camera.bandwidth;
            metaData.height = camera.height;
            metaData.width = camera.width;
            metaData.keyFrameInterval = camera.keyFrameInterval;
            metaData.copyright = "company";
            netStream.send("@setDataFrame", "onMetaData", metaData);

        }

        isRecording = true
        startClockTimer()

        publishButton.gotoAndPlay(2)
        publishButton.buttonMode = true
        publishButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, publishButton$click);


        limitTimer.start()
    }

    /*
     *  redirect to finishURL that was passed via flashvars
     * */
    private function publishButton$click(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stopPublish()

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(dataHolder.finishURL)
        navigateToURL(request, "_self")
    }

    private function stopPublish():void
    {
        netStream.close();
        connection.close();

        limitTimer.stop();
        clockTimer.stop();

        isRecording = false

        recordStatus.gotoAndStop("recordEnd")

        updateTimer();
    }
    /*
     *  init microphone
     * */
    private function initMicropone():void
    {
        microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone()
        addMicSettings()
    }
    /*
     *  init camera
     * */
    private function initCamera():void
    {
        camera = Camera.getCamera()
        addCameraSettings()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled on creating a php script that sits in the folder with the FLV files. Via a cron job, this php file checks the mysql database for new videos with a process tag of 1. Finds new video? Execute ffmpeg on the FLV file to convert it to mp4 and set the process tag to 0. This way, I maintain the FLV for desktop browser streaming and an MP4 file for iOS streaming. If I should ever need to create another file type for android or whatever may come out, I can simply do another ffmpeg conversion when the cron job triggers.

This would also cause less overhead on the server. The mp4 is encoded once by ffmpeg - not every time a request is made to stream the file via FMS. Now the MP4 is just another file on the web server.